# How can I stop camelot-py from splitting multi-line text in a single cell into multiple cells?

Tags: python, python-camelot

I am trying to build an app which reads arbitrary PDFs and extracts tables from them and I am using [Camelot](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/) for extracting the tables. This is working fine for tables in which cells have single line values. However, for tables having cells with multi-line values, Camelot is splitting the multi-line text in a single cell, into multiple cells. Since Camelot is built on top of pdfminer, I tried to tweak the layout analysis parameters (specifically **line_margin**) to make Camelot not split the lines. However, the issue remains.

What other parameters can I tweak to handle this issue? Here is an example of the tables which have this issue.
[image]

I do not want to use the 'lattice' flavor as most of the tables that I expect to see do not have demarcating lines.

Comment: In my experience, with 'stream' flavor, each line becomes a row.

Comment: Yes, that behavior is causing the problem. Is there a way to override the behavior?

Comment: @RohitGavval any luck on this? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your PDFs tables have lines that are brighter than the cells, as in your example, then you might try lattice flavour with process_background=True.

`tables = camelot.read_pdf('background_lines.pdf', process_background=True)`

See, https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html